# Getting node connection in a Saved Model from Tensorflow Hub

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-hub

When I try to get the model from tensorflow-hub resporitory.
I can see it as a Saved Model format, but I cant get access to model architecture.

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
model = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/centernet/hourglass_512x512/1")
)
```

I have tried to switch to the serving model `model_serv = model.signatures["serving_default"]`.
I can get the variables from `model_serv.variables`, but I cannot know which one is the input of which one.

```
(<tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 32) dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[[[-3.97976696e-01, -1.39825698e-02,  1.48418739e-01,
            2.21630976e-01,  1.22568436e-01,  2.75629699e-01,
           -1.62098631e-01, -8.73222947e-02, -8.37984905e-02,
           -1.07462037e+00, -5.02275899e-02, -7.41135418e-01,
            7.73177087e-01,  9.39219058e-01,  1.36517823e-01,
           -1.02845311e-01,  1.99863434e-01, -8.84439111e-01,
            1.18872988e+00,  3.60081524e-01,  1.87927604e-01,
            7.68159032e-01, -3.77650857e-01,  1.29962599e+00,
           -5.90088740e-02,  9.43712473e-01, -9.02807772e-01,
            4.63794529e-01,  3.14643413e-01,  3.56451869e-01,
           -6.45827428e-02, -5.81295252e-01],
          [-3.56151998e-01,  8.24032575e-02, -2.18966097e-01,
            2.63993502e-01, -5.06394394e-02,  3.73886883e-01,
           -2.11740986e-01, -1.72393456e-01,  1.75810307e-01,
           -1.57683456e+00, -5.35937473e-02,  1.54716182e+00,
            9.20912862e-01,  1.25239062e+00, -5.14700040e-02,
            2.70201236e-01, -9.94481087e-01, -8.18459511e-01,
           -9.33381915e-01, -4.58403789e-02, -2.87465602e-01,
```

I have look for the `model_serv.graph`, but it also doesn't point out for me the node's connection between these variables.

Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the SavedModels served on TF Hub encapsulate the model architecture. (Reverse-engineering is possible but tedious.) To study and perhaps modify the architecture, the best option is to go to the source code, see section Source on that model's documentation page.

Comment: Can you give any example that I can inspect on? Even though it is tedious :(